# How to debug ssh connection to remote user (when connection to root works fine)

Tags: ssh, fedora, openssh, ssh-keys, xubuntu

I have an Xubuntu "Caller" and Fedora "Callee" in my garage.  I'm setting them up to connect via SSH.  Both are running OpenSSH, so the configurations are similar.

I can connect as the root account on both systems, but I am unable to connect to the sole user account on the Callee from the Caller's root or user accounts.

I have verified that the authorized-keys record for the Caller's root account is identical in both root and user on the Callee, so I would expect root to be able to connect to the user. There is a minimal log of the failure in Callee's `/var/log/security` file, and a somewhat verbose record in `/var/log/messages`, but neither one gives any details I know how to use. They both basically say it failed, and the messages include UID and PID info.  It just seems the cryptology broke.

How can I find out more? Where should I look? What should I check?

ADDITIONAL INFO:
the error message is

> kevin@Callee: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

The failure occurs when calling the user, but not when calling the root, if exactly the same contents are in the authorized-keys of both accounts on the Callee.

In the user account,

```
drwx------. 2 kevin kevin 4096 Jan 17 06:34 .ssh
```

and

```
-rw-------. 1 kevin kevin  96 Jan 17 06:34 authorized-keys
```

When I try the -v switch on ssh, with the root Caller trying to contact first root then the user on the Callee, the root call succeeds but the user call fails.  The -v outputs are identical except for the name of the target down to and including the line

```
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:6QuMnJvYJWqqoQ0ASVbUJvgWdR5Grzb2r8IxiYUmNho
```

but when connecting to root the next line says "Server accepts key" whereas  at the same spot the user says

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
```

and continues with vain attempts for just a few lines.  Trying the same with ssh -vvv does not give any additional useful information.

So the Callee as user does not like the same key that it liked as root, despite the authorized-keys files being identical.  What gives?

Comment: Might help if you edited your question to add the error messages. To me, this sounds like a possible permissions issue in the Callee user directory path. Meaning, check `~/.ssh` permissions (should be `700`) and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (should be `600`) and make sure the correct SSH public key is in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. As for your own debugging, check the output of `ssh -v Callee host` or even `ssh -vv Callee host` or even `ssh -vvv Callee host` for verbose output and check where it hangs and falls.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks.  And I added a bunch more info.

Comment: As [the answer by @Kenster explains](https://superuser.com/a/1763404/167207), `authorized-keys` is incorrect. It needs to be `authorized_keys`. Happy this was a simple issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-rw-------. 1 kevin kevin  96 Jan 17 06:34 authorized-keys
```

This file should normally be called *authorized_keys* with an underscore instead of a dash. Sshd [looks for the underscore form by default](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthorizedKeysFile).

Comment: Thanks!  Even though I now feel like a fool, because that solved a riddle that stumped me for a couple of days.